# Não consigo usar o valor passado em argv na chamada do programa

Tags: c, c++

Quando digito `b` na chamada do programa ele não me retorna o `Bom dia`. Gostaria de entender o que está errado no meu código. Segue o programa abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv []){
  
  if (argv[1] == 'b'){
      printf("Bom dia");
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (*argv[1] == 'b'){`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O parâmetro `argv` é um *array* de *arrays* de *chars*. Quando você usa `argv[1]`, o que você está acessando na verdade é um ponteiro para o inicio do *array* de *chars* que representa o segundo argumento passado para o programa.

Na linha `argv[1] == 'b'`, como `argv[1]` e `'b'` são de tipos diferentes o compilador faz um *cast* implícito das variáveis. Nesse caso o que é comparado é valor de `argv[1]`, um endereço de memoria, com `98`, que é o valor ASCII do caractere `'b'`, como os dois sempre são diferentes a comparação falha.

Também saiba que embora o seguinte código compile, ele pode não produzir o que você espera.

```c
char str1[] = "abc";
char str2[] = "abc";

if (str1 == str2) {
    printf("iguais");
} else {
    printf("diferentes");
}
```

Quando você acessa só o nome do *array* o que você recebe é o ponteiro pro primeiro elemento dele, por isso o que é comparado são os endereços de memória, não o conteúdo das *strings*.

Pra você comparar *strings*, que em C são apenas *arrays* de *chars* terminadas em **`NULL`**, você precisa usar a função `strcmp` do cabeçalho `string.h`

Essa função recebe duas *strings* e retorna:

- < 0 se `str1` é menor que `str2`
- > 0 se `str1` é maior que `str2`
- 0 se `str1` e `str2` são iguais

O seu código corrigido ficaria assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv []){
  if (argc < 2) return 0;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "b") == 0){
      printf("Bom dia");
  }
}
```

Note que você sempre deve verificar se o número correto de argumentos foram passados para o programa antes de acessar algum valor de `argv`, caso contrario seu programa pode acessar lixo da memória, o que pode produzir resultados inesperados.

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela resposta, foi de grande ajuda. Consegui entender perfeitamente onde eu estava errando e consegui tirar um bom aprendizado disso. Agora, saberia me explicar o por que de quando eu executar o programa sem passar nenhum parâmetro ele me retorna Segmentation fault? Grato desde já.

Comment: @kodakz Como eu disse na resposta, você deve sempre verificar se o numero de argumentos está correto de acordo com o numero esperado. O argumento `argc` guarda o numero de argumentos passados para o programa. Você pode colocar um bloco `if` no inicio da função `main` que faz esta checagem: `if (argc < 2) return 0;` assim o programa termina a execução sem problemas. Editei a resposta pra incluir este trecho.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` é [um arranjo de ponteiros](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ericko/rt_lt.rule.html).

Melhor escrever:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv []){
    if (argc < 2) return 0;
    if (*argv[1] == 'b'){
        printf("Bom dia");
    }
}
```

ou

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv []){
    if (argc < 2) return 0;
    if (argv[1][0] == 'b'){
        printf("Bom dia");
    }
}
```

Comment: Grato pela resposta, muito bom ver diferentes maneiras de executar o mesmo programa.

Comment: @kodakz, Obrigado!